# How to find whether patent is pending or granted and its issue date, if granted

Tags: legal-status, validity, date

This particular patent has been applied long ago. How can I find out if the patent has ever been granted or is still pending. If the patent has been granted, I want to know the date of it's issue. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of several search tools.  One that I like is Espacenet run by the European Patent Office.  I provided the application number (not the publication number) and this is the URL to get to the results.

http://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?ST=singleline&locale=en_EP&submitted=true&DB=&query=DE19883828825

Selecting INPADOC Legal Status from the list on the left gives a bare bones answer that on June 17, 1992 this application was withdrawn.   You can probably get more information on a German patent office site or you can contact someone that works with German patents to give you more information.

Espacenet has a disclaimer that they try to have accurate information but notes that mistakes can happen.  If this is critical to you, you should have your patent attorney dig a little deeper, most have relationships with European patent attorneys that are familiar with these systems.